# Track events with Google analytics and angular.js

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

So the problem is "I cant track an event" in angular web application.
I put this in my test.html:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');    
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');      
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">    
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);    
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();    
</script>
```

And it works great!! I can see the traking of my web page in google Analytics, but I need more, I need to track some events and I tried:

1.First try:
in test.html

```
<!--some code here-->
<button ng-click="some()">test</button>
```

in app.js file

```
var app= angular.module('bp',['ui.bootstrap','ngTouch']);   
        app.controller('BpController',['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache){
    $scope.value='GotIt';
    $scope.some = function(){
    //some code here
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'main', 'search', 'service', $scope.value]);
    };
    }]);
```

and no trace of my event in google analytics

2. second try:

in test.html

```
<!--some code here-->
<button ng-click="" analyticsevent value="GotIt">test</button>
```

in app.js file

```
   var app= angular.module('bp',['ui.bootstrap','ngTouch']);   
    app.controller('BpController',['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache){    
}]).directive('analyticsevent', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            value: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function (e) {
                $(function () {
                //some code here
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'main', 'search', 'service', scope.value]);
                });                
                 });
        }
    };     
    });;
```

3. Third try:
   I use some called 'angulartics' but it cause a lot of problems in HTML rendering, so I can't use it.

All of them don't work :(
Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code looks like you're sending the pageview hit twice - once with universal, and a second time with "classic". Have you considered tag management; in particular, Google Tag Manager? I've successfully tagged angular sites with virtual pageviews (you could just as easily do events).

It's not absolutely necessary though. The core requirement is that you implement an onclick listener for these events.

Comment: Thanks, I' reading the Google Tag tutorial https://support.google.com/tagmanager/, I looks very easy more than Google Analytics Events, its easy capture cliks, that I need